# Spacetime distances and perception

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, distance, perception

My question is about how things appear in human perception vs how things are in spacetime.

Take as an example my perception of the laptop screen while I am writing this.

As far as I understand it, according to the theory of relativity, before the light from the screen reaches me, the laptop is space-like separated from me. After the light has reached me (and I have perceived the laptop), it becomes a part of my light-cone and it is now time-like separated from me.

If I am right about the above, what determines when and how one event crosses the light-cone 'barrier,' and goes from space-like to time-like separated?

I am self-learning and theory of relativity (both STR and GTR) and I apologize if my current reasoning is confused. Looking forward to your answers and clarifications!

Comment: "The laptop" is not an event. An event is a specific point in space *and* time, so something like "the laptop screen at 12:00" is an event, and is different from the event "the laptop screen at 12:01". Two events are separated by a spacetime interval, which is invariant (the same for all observers) and which never changes. So I think your question is based on a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space-like and time-like are not defined based on when light reaches you. It is defined based on what the value of interval($\Delta s^2$) is between two events. An event is basically a set of coordinates in the space time given meaning by (x,y,z,t). As you know $ \Delta s^2=-(c\Delta t)^2 + \Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2$.

If $\Delta s^2 <0$ then its called a timelike separation and if $\Delta s^2>0$ then its a spacelike separation. If its zero its light like.

Physically, a timelike separation means that there exists a reference frame where the two events occur at the same place but at different times. From a human perspective, this means that no matter what happens, you can find some weird reference frame where you can stay in one place and the two events will eventually happen exactly where you are observing from. So one happens after the other. These type of events preserve causality, which means that the cause and effect relation is maintained. In your case, the events are turning on the laptop and the second event is light reaching your eyes. If you calculate the interval (as defined above) you will find that it is less than zero making these two set of events timelike. A similar way of arriving at this answer is to realize that the light will only reach your eyes AFTER the laptop is turned on, thus it has to be timelike separated.

A spacelike separation means that a reference frame exists where the two events occur at the same time but at different places.  Again, from a human perspective, this means you can change your frame of reference such that you will see two events happen simultaneously but at different locations.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. Could also please give an example of space-like separated events in my vicinity? Are any of the events in ordinary human life space-like separated?

Comment: I think any non-related events can somehow be made space-like. Lets assume at some time 't', a solar flare erupts. At 't+10', you sneeze. Are these two events spacelike? Do a small calculation. $\Delta x^2-c^2 \Delta t^2$. Since it takes 8 minutes for light to reach us, we can calculate $\Delta x=c*8*60$ m and we know $\Delta t =10 s$. This makes $\Delta s^2$ a positive quantity, making it spacelike

Comment: Thanks! So basically, if I got this right, for any two events A and B, as long as light cannot reach A from B (and vice-versa), these two events are space-like separated?

Comment: @Maverick Yes, you are correct .

Comment: @Maverick Given enough time light can reach anywhere. As long as c*t<distance between events A&B then its a spacelike .